# sakis3g on raspberry pi2 not accepting any other interface other than ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1.. how to make connection on other ttyUSB*

Tags: usb, internet

i am newbie to linux and raspberry pi. On my raspberry pi 2 , i use sakis3g to make the connection successful,it works fine when it is connected to ttyUSB1 or ttyUSB0 but wen i reboot the system with some other usb devices the ttyUSB# changes and i also change my sakis3g.conf file manually but still . i get a error message which says that selected interface is not valid only usbinterface 0 or usbinterface 1 is valid. i tried many things but everything went in vain.

my question here is ,

1) why does sakis3g doesn't accept any other ttyUSB# other than 0 or 1 . if it can accept then how can i do it ?
 for instance,
if i give USBINTERFACE=3 on my raspberry pi it says selected interface is invalid. 
any help or suggestions will be encouraged!

thank you.

Comment: my solution: i had to set priority to my usb device compared to all other attached devices (on reboot). i did it by disabling and enabling ports